# "I don't feel like cook tonight." or "I don't feel like to cook tonight." or "I don't feel like cooking tonight."

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I met this sentence structure "don't feel like", but I am not sure with what the next should be. Here are three sentences.

> "I don't feel like **cook** tonight."

or

> "I don't feel like **to cook** tonight."

or

> "I don't feel like **cooking** tonight."

Which ones are correct and easily understandable, if any?

Comment: I don't understand why the question was down-voted.

Comment: @TRomano, I'm not the down-voter, but probably because it doesn't show any research effort (google search of "feel like" instantly answers the question)

Answer (score 2):

"Fell like" [requires](http://www.talkenglish.com/lessondetails.aspx?ALID=2023) gerund, so the correct form is "I don't feel like cooking tonight".

Comment: Not exactly. It's the preposition *like* which will only take NPs or --ing forms as a Complement. The *feel* is a red herring.

Answer (score 2):

*To feel like something* (a noun or a verb + ing) * is [an idiomatic expression](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/feel+like) meaning

1. to seem likely to do something
2. to have a desire or an inclination for doing or having something.

> It feels like rain.
>
> I feel like a cup of tea.
>
> I don't feel like going out tonight.
>
> I don't feel like cooking now.

*To feel like* followed by a verb + ing is a set usage, and there's no way to use *to + infinitive with the expression.